# Why are my log4j2 rolling logs including previous days' log entries?

Tags: java, tomcat, logging, log4j2

I'm using log4j 2.5 for Tomcat web application logging. There's two application servers that both write to the same log file on a network path.

My log files are snowballing in size because each new day's log file contains all of the previous days' entries.

For example, myLog-2016-06-01.log contains all of the logging from 5-20 (day of implementation) to 06-01, and myLog-05-31, contains everything from 5-20 to 5-31, and so on...

I'm assuming there's something I'm not understanding about how the XML configuration file works.

Relevant info from log4j2.xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
<Configuration status="trace">  
<Appenders>  
    <RollingRandomAccessFile name="RollingFileLogger" 
                             fileName="[...]\myLog.log" 
                             filePattern="[...]\myLog-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log">
        <PatternLayout pattern="%n %n %d ${hostName} %p %c: %msg"/>  
        <Policies>
            <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy/>
        </Policies>
        <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="10"/>
    </RollingRandomAccessFile>
    <Console name="ConsoleLogger" target="SYSTEM_OUT"> 
        <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
    </Console>
</Appenders>  
<Loggers>  
    <Root level="trace">  
        <AppenderRef ref="RollingFileLogger"/>
        <AppenderRef ref="ConsoleLogger"/>  
    </Root>  
</Loggers>
```

Comment: "There's two application servers that both write to the same log file on a network path" - that could be the problem. You need to use some special appenders to write simultaneously from several applications to one log, like `SocketAppender` or `SyslogAppender`.

Comment: I'll investigate those, thanks. I'm also going to try separate files (one on a local filesystem instead) in order to confirm for sure that this is my only issue.

Comment: That's the problem. I'm going to attempt to set up a SocketAppender, then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per [Roman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5032339/roman)'s comment, the answer was to use a [SocketAppender](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/net/SocketAppender.html) and accompanying socket server to funnel all logger calls from all webapps into a single appender. Works perfectly now.